# Load top 5 records per date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, in which there are date wise quiz score of different users. I want to load top 5 scorers for every date.

**Table sample create statement**:

```
CREATE TABLE `subscriber_score` (
  `msisdn` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `score` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

  `total_questions_sent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

  `total_correct_answers` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_wrong_answers` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

  PRIMARY KEY (`msisdn`,`date`),
  KEY `fk_subscriber_score_subscriber1` (`msisdn`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subscriber_score_subscriber1` FOREIGN KEY (`msisdn`) REFERENCES `subscriber` (`msisdn`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Query which I have tried**:

```
SELECT subscriber.msisdn AS msisdn,subscriber.name AS name,subscriber.gender AS gender,tmp2.score AS score,tmp2.date AS winning_date 
FROM subscriber,
    (SELECT msisdn,tmp.date,tmp.score 
     FROM subscriber_score,
          (SELECT date,MAX(score) AS score 
           FROM subscriber_score 
           WHERE date > '2014-10-10' AND date < '2014-11-10' GROUP BY date) 
          tmp 
     WHERE subscriber_score.date=tmp.date AND subscriber_score.score=tmp.score) 
tmp2 
WHERE subscriber.msisdn=tmp2.msisdn ORDER BY winning_date
```

**Actual output:** Only one top scorer for every date is shown.

**Wanted Output** Top 5(or say 10) records for every date are required.

Comment: 5 of what?  Edit your question and provide sample output and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this using variables to assign each row a row number, then filter the top 5 for each date.

```
SELECT  s.name AS name,
        s.gender AS gender,
        s.msisdn,
        ss.date,
        ss.score
FROM    (   SELECT  ss.msisdn,
                    ss.score,
                    @r:= CASE WHEN ss.Date = @d THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END AS RowNum,
                    @d:= ss.date AS winning_date
            FROM    subscriber_score AS ss
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @d:= '', @r:= 0) AS v
            WHERE   ss.date > '2014-10-10' 
            AND     ss.date < '2014-11-10'
            ORDER  BY ss.Date, ss.Score DESC
        ) AS ss
        INNER JOIN Subscriber AS s
            ON s.msisdn = ss.msisdn
WHERE   ss.RowNum <= 5;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/792d0/2)**

Comment: This is the right way to do it in MySQL, although it may require some fine tuning like initializing @d with start date, for example.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it. Let me fit into my scenario, and tell you later.

Answer (score 0):

refer this query  its not complete but hope it helps

```
SELECT SCORE
FROM table
WHERE date='somedate'
ORDER BY SCORE DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This gives records of only one date. I need 5 records for every date in the selected date range.

Comment: verify whether you have 5 records for that particular date.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  bc.msisdn msisdn,bc.name name,bc.gender gender,ab.score score,ab.date winning_date
    (
       select msisdn,date,score,
       dense_rank() over (partition by date order by score desc) rnk 
        from subscriber_score
     ) ab,subscriber bc
 where bc.msisdn=ab.msisdn and ab.rnk<=5 
 order by winning_date     ;
```

This is how you can get solution of your problem in oracle sql.

Comment: but his question is also tagged with sql

Comment: otherwise he has to declare it in his question that he looking for the result in mysql

Comment: thats why @amenadiel i wrote below my query that how one can do it in oracle sql

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
     SELECT subscriber.msisdn AS msisdn,subscriber.name AS name,subscriber.gender AS gender,tmp2.score AS score,tmp2.date AS winning_date 
      FROM subscriber inner join
      (select msisdn,date, score, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY score DESC) AS Row
       FROM subscriber_score 
       WHERE date > '2014-10-10' AND date < '2014-11-10' GROUP BY date) 
      tmp 
     on subscriber.msisdn=tmp.msisdn and tmp.row<=5
```

Comment: He's using MySQL, there's no OVER/PARTITION in MySQL

Comment: @nitubansal even i wrote same query with dense rank ... i think he should mention that he is looking for the result in mysql also his  question is tagged with sql  and it could be any sql

Comment: nowhere is written that query should be in sql or MySQL and there is nothing wrong in approach and may be useful for someone looking for sql approach.